# libvirt qemu AppArmor 9p hard links

Tags: libvirt, hardlink, apparmor, 9p

I am using libvirt with qemu on a debian host. One virtual machine has a 9p mount point defined:

```
<filesystem type='mount' accessmode='mapped'>
  <source dir='/mnt/pool/share'/>
  <target dir='share'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</filesystem>
```

The default apparmor configuration (which is apparently created by `virt-aa-helper`) does not allow me to create hard links on the 9p volume.

I made it work by adding the following line to `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu`

```
  "/mnt/pool/share/**" rwl,
```

This works but has the following problems:

1. It allows *all* hosts to read/write to this directory, not only the one host I need
2. It requires editing a conffile that is regularly updated which is probably not a good idea because it makes updates to the debian package harder
3. It is not configured in the libvirt xml file which makes portability harder and is one extra step

**Is there a better way?**